# Broken axis without mutiplot

Tags: gnuplot

I want to plot a histogram with broken axis on Y. A good tutorial has been explained [here](http://gnuplot-tricks.blogspot.fr/2010/06/broken-axis-once-more.html) and [here](http://www.phyast.pitt.edu/~zov1/gnuplot/html/broken.html) but they don't fit my need. The data points are

```
"Method"   "Year1"   "Year2"
   M1        12        -40
   M2        5         40
```

The code snippet for this data points are

```
set ylabel "The Profit (%)"
set style data histogram
set style histogram cluster gap 1

# Draw a horizontal line at Y=0    
set arrow 1 from -1,0 to 2,0 nohead

plot 'test_data.txt' using 2:xtic(1) ti col lc rgb "black", '' u 3 ti col lc rgb "grey"
```

And the output looks like

[image]

As you can see the grey bars are on the extreme values. What I want is to limit the yrange from - to +20 and put a `~~` symbol (rotate it by 90 degree) on the second bars and put a label -40 and +40. Something like this figure

[image]

How that is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it, but it is very tedious:

1. Crop the y-values in the `using` statement of your histograms
2. Plot a label with the `labels` plotting style when the value is above or below a given limit.
3. Plot the vectors, which show, that the boxes are truncated.

The following script works:

```
set ylabel "The Profit (%)"
set style histogram cluster gap 1
set boxwidth 0.9 relative

# Draw a horizontal line at Y=0    
set xzeroaxis lt -1
ulim = 15
llim = -15
set yrange[-20:20]

sc = 0.333

set style fill solid noborder

plot 'test_data.txt' using ($2 > ulim ? ulim : ($2 < llim ? llim : $2)):xtic(1) ti col lc rgb "black" with histogram, \
     '' u ($3 > ulim ? ulim : ($3 < llim ? llim : $3))  ti col lc rgb "grey" with histogram,\
     for [c=2:3] '' u ($0-1+(c-2.5)*sc):(column(c) > ulim ? ulim : 1/0):(sprintf('+%d', ulim)) with labels offset 0, char 1.5 notitle,\
     for [c=2:3] '' u ($0-1+(c-2.5)*sc):(column(c) < llim ? llim : 1/0):(sprintf('%d', llim)) with labels offset 0, char -1.5 notitle,\
     for [c=2:3] for [ofs=0:1] '' u ($0-1+(c-2.5)*sc - 0.03 + ofs*0.02):\
                                    (column(c) > ulim ? ulim - 1 : (column(c) < llim ? llim - 1 : 1/0)):(0.04):(2) with vectors lc rgb 'black' nohead notitle
```

and gives the following result with 4.6.3:

[image]

There is too much involved to explain everything, so here are some important remarks:

- The histogram boxes are placed starting from 0 and are given a custom label. This is important for the placement of the labels and the vectors (`$0-1` in the using statement).
- The factor `sc = 0.333` results from the three columns for on xtick (year1, year2, and the `gap 1`).
- The method works for both columns 2 and 3
- The script gives some warning, because some plots are empty (no value of column 2 exceeds the limits, so the respective label and vectors plots contain no points).
- I think its not practicable to use curves to indicate the broken boxes.
- If your boxes have borders, they would appear also on top of the broken boxes, which might be counterintuitive.
- Use either `set xzeroaxis` to draw a line at `y=0`, or an arrow with `graph` coordinates (`set arrow from graph 0,first 0 to graph 1, first 0 nohead`).

Comment: Can you explain what does the `for` statement mean? What is `c` in `for [c=2:3]`?

Comment: Excuse me are you sure that the script works? When I paste it and run, I get this error `"test_plot.txt", line 20: ')' expected` and that points to the plot command. I checked the `(` and `)` and they are fine. But don't know why it complains

Comment: Sorry, I had a typo when adding the `sc` variable. The `for [c=2:3]` executes the plot command first with `c=2` and then with `c=3`. I use this to crop both boxes (second and third column), if necessary.